# Difference between async.each vs async.every?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async.js

Difference between async.each vs async.every in **async.js**?
It seems that both are same except that async.every returns the results.
Correct me I'm wrong.

Comment: Read the docs: http://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Async Each**

```
.each(coll, iteratee, callback)
```

It more like array each method. Here on each Iterable ( coll ) element, the function `iteratee` will be executed. This will go on parallel. So taking example from the site

```
async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
  // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Here assume the `openFiles` is array of file paths. So the `saveFile` will be called on each one. The process will be in parallel. So the order of execution is not guaranteed. Here there will be some operation done over the `openFiles` array by `saveFile`. If any of the element causes the error in saveFile, the function will call the mail callback with error and will halt the process.

**Async Every**

```
.every(coll, iteratee, callback)
```

This seems like same method. As it also execute the `iteratee` method over `coll` elements. But the key here is, it will return either `true` or `false`. It is more like a filter but, only difference is it returns `false` if any of the element in `coll` fails in iteratee method. Don't confuse here with an error. Error will be caused if some uncertain behaviour happens while executing. So the `callback` in  method will return `callback(err, result)`. The result will be true or false depending on if the `coll` passes the iteratee test.

For eg check if array has even numbers;

```
async.every([4,2,8,16,19,20,44], function(number, callback) {
      if(number%2 == 0){
         callback(null, true);
      }else{
        callback(null, false);
      }
}, function(err, result) {
    // if result is true when all numbers are even else false
});
```

So its more like, testing set of values in an iterable entity. If they pass a given test. Another example could be checking if given numbers are prime.

Comment: Can we return anything apart from true or false?

Comment: @RaviTeja No, the sole purpose of the method is to filter and return a boolean. I've used that method, you can never get values other than boolean in final callback.

Answer (score 3):

#### each(arr, iterator, [callback])

Applies the function iterator to each item in arr, in parallel. The iterator is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when it has finished. If the iterator passes an error to its callback, the main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the error.

Note, that since this function applies iterator to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order.

Arguments

arr - An array to iterate over.
iterator(item, callback) - A function to apply to each item in arr. The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument. The array index is not passed to the iterator. If you need the index, use forEachOf.
callback(err) - Optional A callback which is called when all iterator functions have finished, or an error occurs.
Examples

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names and saveFile is a function
// to save the modified contents of that file:

async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names

async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

  // Perform operation on file here.
  console.log('Processing file ' + file);

  if( file.length > 32 ) {
    console.log('This file name is too long');
    callback('File name too long');
  } else {
    // Do work to process file here
    console.log('File processed');
    callback();
  }
}, function(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

#### every(arr, iterator, [callback])

Alias: all

Returns true if every element in arr satisfies an async test. The callback for each iterator call only accepts a single argument of true or false; it does not accept an error argument first! This is in-line with the way node libraries work with truth tests like fs.exists.

Arguments

arr - An array to iterate over.
iterator(item, callback) - A truth test to apply to each item in the array in parallel. The iterator is passed a callback(truthValue) which must be called with a boolean argument once it has completed.
callback(result) - Optional A callback which is called as soon as any iterator returns false, or after all the iterator functions have finished. Result will be either true or false depending on the values of the async tests.
Note: the callbacks do not take an error as their first argument.

Example

```
async.every(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.exists, function(result){
    // if result is true then every file exists
});
```